# SQL query to get value from one table as columnName and record values from other table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need your help to get a SQL query.

I have an table 'order' which has  order details. Plus we also have an addition table 'ExtraFields'. This contains the  name of extra fields some of the clients want to populate with the order. ColumnNames are like Id, ClientId, ColumnName...

NOw we also have another table 'ExtraFieldValues'(OrderId,ExtraFieldId,Value....). This has the actual values for the extrafields for any particular order.

Different clients have different ExtraFields like : Notes,'Reason','Additional Req' etc.

Now I need to get a query to return record for order details including these extrafields as column name and values as record in single line.

The tables look like (I have removed some columns to keep it simple)

Order table:

[image]

ExtraField table:

[image]

ExtraFieldValue table:

[image]

The query would run per client so if run the query to get orders for client 98963 it should look like

[image]

I am pretty new to this sql and any pointers would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Please share sample data for these three tables and desired results. It's very difficult to understand the relationships here.

Comment: I have added some sample data, hope it helps understand my question better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found my answer in PIVOT. May not be the best way but works the way I need.
https://www.essentialsql.com/create-dynamic-pivot-table-sql-server/

Here's the query I did, for anyone with similar problem

Had to first get all distinct columNames from extrafield table and then apply pivot on the needed query.

```
DECLARE 
        @Columns as VARCHAR(MAX),
        @SQL as VARCHAR(MAX)

        SELECT @Columns =
        COALESCE(@Columns + ', ','') + QUOTENAME(Name)
        FROM
           (SELECT DISTINCT Name
            FROM   ExtraField
              where ClientId=@CompanyID
           ) AS F
        ORDER BY F.Name

    SET @SQL = 'SELECT RequestedDate,Description, ' + @Columns + '
    FROM
    (
     SELECT order.Created as RequestedDate,
            order.Description as Description,
             ExtraFieldValue.value AS Value,
            ExtraField.Name as Name
     FROM   
        order
        left join ExtraFieldValue on  ExtraFieldValue.OderID=Order.ID 
        left JOIN ExtraField  ON ExtraField.Id = ExtraFieldValue.ExtraFieldID 

    ) as PivotData
    PIVOT
    (
       Max(Value)
       FOR Name IN (' + @Columns + ')
    ) AS PivotResult'

    exec(@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

Key/value tables are a nuisance. If you know which extra columns to select, use correlated subqueries:

```
select
  o.description,
  o.createdate,
  (
    select efv.value
    from extrafieldvalue efv
    where efv.orderid = o.id 
    and efv.extrafieldid = (select id from extrafield where columnname = 'AdditionalInfo')
  ) as additionalinfo,
  (
    select efv.value
    from extrafieldvalue efv
    where efv.orderid = o.id 
    and efv.extrafieldid = (select id from extrafield where columnname = 'Notes')
  ) as notes
from orders o;
```

If you don't know what extra columns to select, then select everything and use your app's or Webpage's programming language to find out which columns to display.